# Loading created by ProgressDialog wouldn't stop , how to hide progressbar when page is loaded

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, webview, progress-bar

I'm new to Java and was trying to create a web-view app. The loading widget was created using Progress Dialog but it wouldn't stop. I don't know what is wrong. Please help.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView mywebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...",true);
    mywebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mywebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mywebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    mywebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if(pd!=null && pd.isShowing())
            {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    mywebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");
    mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WvClient());
}
private class WvClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError er) {
        handler.proceed();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mywebView.canGoBack())
    {
        mywebView.goBack();
    }
    else
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You have declared setWebViewClient twice , ie after load url you again
> declared the setWebViewClient with your custom client , correct answer is

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebView;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ProgressDialog pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...",true);
        mywebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        mywebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        if(pd!=null && pd.isShowing())
            {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
         if(pd!=null && pd.isShowing())
            {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
    }
});
        mywebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");
        
    }
   
    
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mywebView.canGoBack())
        {
            mywebView.goBack();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this but the pd in following code is turning red. I don't know what that means.

@Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if(pd!=null && pd.isShowing())
            {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        }

Comment: Now it says that it cannot find the symbol getActivity() in
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cannot load page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: remove this line Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cannot load page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); , updated my answer

Comment: I changed it to getApplication() and its working. Hope it doesn't break anything else ;). Thank you soo much.

Comment: i am glad it worked , please upvote and check the tick icon also

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments

Comment: There is a black screen for about 2 secs before loading widget appears. Is there someway to remove that?

Comment: post your xml and also post stack trace from logcat

Answer (score 0):

Place a breakpoint in

```
onPageFinished
```

and see if the listener actually get called?